# Doctrine filter with "JOINED" Inheritance

Tags: symfony, filter, doctrine-orm

I have JOINED inheritance, and I want to have a doctrine filter on sub class, but in filter class I get only superClass and can't set filter, because superclass table hasn't such columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should use directly the repository of the subclass. In this way, Doctrine will automatically filter them for you, and you will work with all the columns available to the subclass.